# D Flip Flop design using multiplexer

Tags: flipflop, sequential-logic

I was trying to implement a simple D Flip Flop using 2 multiplexers.

[image: d flip flop]

Are there any errors in design?

Do you have any other suggestions about design? Thanks.

**Update:**
As you'd recognise I've not implemented the clock signal yet.

I used this example when designing the circuit.
[image: D Flip Flop]

There are two latches. When C=0, Q holds its old value Q' follows the input D. When C=1 Q' holds its old value Q follows Q'.

Comment: Does it work? What are your goals for the design? Are you planning to actually built it or just simulate it?

Comment: I was watching a lecture about sequential circuits. At the end of the lecture they ask how to make a latch using a lenient multiplexor.  They show you different latch designs and want you to find out which one works correctly. Or may be one design might work but use more gates than necessary.  To be able to answer these questions I thought it was necessary to simulate my own designs. This way I would have learned what worked and what didn't.

Answer (score 1):

The truth-table for a D-FF is

D Q | Q+1
0 0 | 0
0 1 | 0
1 0 | 1
1 0 | 1

So, your circuit does not work. At least my simulation tells me this

[image: LTSpice_circuit]

[image: LTSpice_simulation]

- Qn gets high while Q is high also
- Qn is not high when Q is low
- Q is only high when D and C are high... as soon as C gets low, Q also is low - but it should hold the value

---

Edit 2: added inverters as suggested in comment

[image: Circuit]

[image: Plots]

So corrected inverters a second time (sorry it was almost 2 o clock in the night).

I still see Outputs changing when clock is low, and Qn not being the inverse of Q

Still wrong... or?

Comment: Questioner's circuit needs the delayed clock for the 2nd stage, you have removed the delay.

Comment: There's A8. What is it's logic function when compared to the previous wire to the same place in A5?

Comment: you are right... shouldnt do such stuff that late

Comment: Still wrong? Yes. You have still same clock in both stages.

Comment: No, the original just has 2 inverters in parallel doing the same... so its the same signal and you can reduce it to 1

Comment: Ok. But try to insert more to see if it gets fixed (assuming your gates and inverters have delay).

Comment: Should DQ finSlentry be 11?

Answer (score 0):

You must have a lenient MUX for this to work, and the MUXs you are using are not lenient.  That is your problem.

Comment: You need something like this to make it lenient.  See section 7.7.1 in this link.  https://computationstructures.org/notes/combinational_logic/notes.html